# How to automate insertion of HTML code in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I have to add same HTML code when send some emails through Mozilla Thunderbird.
(The HTML code helps me to know email is read or not)
Now I just insert the code manually.

How can I automate the process?
Can I create button for the insertion?
Is there any addon for such task?

Answer (score 0):

Try the SmartTemplate Addon. 
You can create E-Mail templates with it.

Comment: ty. I've tried the addon. But now I have same template for all my new emails. I don't need the additional HTML code for all my emails. But only sometimes. Perhaps I have to create additional account for such emails.

Comment: Okay. I don't know if there's an addon that fit these special cases.